# Disable submit button if email is invalid using Jquery with RegEx

Tags: jquery, regex

can you show me some examples of disabling a submit button when the email is invalid with RegEx on it? It would be great if your answer or explanation is simple so that newbies can understand like me :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Justinas's answer is good. I recommend to modify as follows:

- use `.on('input')` instead of `.on('change')` so that the validation is done on each keystroke, not just on blur
- add visual clue that the button is disabled (gray button)
- add visual clue that the email is invalid (red border)

```js
// Start script when everything is loaded
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Email regex. It's very generic: check if "@" is present and has ".abc" end.
  // There is no 100% correct email regex.
  var emailRegex = /^\w+@\w+\.\w{3}$/;

  // Add event to be triggered on input field change
  $('#email').on('input', function() {
    // Disable or enable submit button depending on regex validation
    if(emailRegex.test($(this).val())) {
      // valid: remove CSS to warn, and enable submit button
      $(this).removeClass('redBorder');
      $('#submit').removeClass('grayText').prop('disabled', 0);
    } else {
      // invalid: add CSS to warn, and disable submit button
      $(this).addClass('redBorder');
      $('#submit').addClass('grayText').prop('disabled', 1);
    }
  });

  // trigger input to trigger validation
  $('#email').trigger('input');
});
```

```css
.redBorder {
  border: 1px solid #f03333
}
.grayText {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email"/>

<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add event on input field to trigger validation function.

If `emailRegex` does not match, set `disabled` property to submit button. Else remove that property

```js
// Start script when everything is loaded
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Email regex. It's very generic: check if "@" is present and has ".abc" end.
  // There is no 100% correct email regex.
  var emailRegex = /\w+@\w+\.\w{3}/;

  // Add event to be triggered on input field change
  $('#email').on('change', function() {
    // Disable or enable submit button depending on regex validation
    $('#submit').prop('disabled', emailRegex.test($(this).val()) == false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email"/>

<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```